# How to build Spark SBT for Spark version 1.5.2

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, bigdata

I've executed a Spark SBT Build Command (build/sbt assembly).

when I execute the following command. I got the error, "Failed to Build".
$ bin/spark-shell

```
Failed to find Spark assembly in /spark-1.5.2/assembly/target/scala-2.10.
You need to build Spark before running this program.
```

Comment: Could you provide some of the output around the build/sbt assembly - it looks like the build didnt complete for some reason.

Comment: Alternatively if you dont need to build from source - you could download the prebuilt binaries for 1.5.2 http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html (select prebuilt from the drop down)